# Dynamic add items to listview using arrayadapter Android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Im using Custom class to fill Adapter on ListView
Class looks like that:

```
package com.example.raidplanner;

public class RaidWpis {
    private int id;
    private int id_gildia;
    private String nazwa;
    private int schemat;
    private int data_zapis;
    private int data_start;
    private int opis;
    private int id_officer;
    private int nick_officer;
    private int typ;

    public RaidWpis(int id,String nazwa) {
        setNazwa(nazwa);
        setId(id);
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id; 
    }       

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id; 
    }

    public String getNazwa() {
        return nazwa;}

    public void setNazwa(String nazwa) {
        this.nazwa = nazwa;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.nazwa;
    }
    public String toString2() {
        return this.id+" - "+nazwa;
    }

}
```

In my activity Im using this code

```
RaidWpis[] items = {
    new RaidWpis(1, "aaaa"),
    new RaidWpis(3, "bbbb"),
    new RaidWpis(6, "cccc"),
    new RaidWpis(11, "dddd"),
    new RaidWpis(17, "eeee"),
};

mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );

ArrayAdapter<RaidWpis> raidList = new ArrayAdapter<RaidWpis>(this, R.layout.simplerow, items);

// Create ArrayAdapter using the raid list.
mainListView.setAdapter(raidList);
```

Now how to add new items to items array. Finaly I want to fill that items array with data from json data (passed from PHP)

Comment: Parse the JSON response and add it your items

Comment: You should use an `ArrayList` instead of an array; you can't dynamically modify an array (it's a fixed size).

Comment: can you help me out with some code sample?

Comment: Sry for bumping up, but I realny need to figure it out, how to add new  data to items array (for example in FOR iteration), thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did it, just changed some code to that:

```
ArrayList<RaidWpis> raid_list = new ArrayList<RaidWpis>();
    raid_list.add(new RaidWpis(1, "aaaa"));
    raid_list.add(new RaidWpis(3, "bbb"));
    raid_list.add(new RaidWpis(5, "ccc"));
    ArrayAdapter<RaidWpis> raidList=new ArrayAdapter<RaidWpis>(this, R.layout.simplerow, raid_list);
```