# Why I cant see values in the spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm creating an Activity with 2 Spinners.
One Spinner gets its items from `strings.xml`

The second Spinner gets its item dynamically (`onCreate()` method).

I can see just the values of the first Spinner and can't see the values of the second one ("bla - 1", "bla 2").

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ChooseContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_contact);

        // set howOften_spinner
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.howOften_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.howOften, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        Spinner spiner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.contacts_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerAdapter.add("bla - 1");
        spinnerAdapter.add("bla - 2");
        spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        spiner2.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.root.databaseexample.ChooseContactActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/contacts_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/howOften_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you notify data set changed after you have set adapter?

Comment: What happened after the changes?

Comment: nothing, same results

Comment: I don't think `notifyDataSetChanged()` is necessary since the data is added before calling `setAdapater()` and this is all in `onCreate()`.

Comment: I see your adapters have different data types CharSequence and String?

Comment: You don't need to notify the adapter if you use its add method, by the way

Comment: I have 2 adapters, one to each spinner

Comment: Is there a reason that one adapter is declared as `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>` and the other is declared as `ArrayAdapter<String>`? Either of these is fine. It would make more sense to declare both with the same time.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted here. I believe the problem is somewhere else in your code. Can you provide a screenshot showing what happens when you click on the second spinner?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have not provided an array or `List` to store the values. You should create an `ArrayList` with the values you want to display. Then use one of the `ArrayAdapter` constructors which includes a `List` parameter. See [Dynamic add items to listview using arrayadapter Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327410/dynamic-add-items-to-listview-using-arrayadapter-android) for more details.

Comment: Using the ArrayAdapter constructor that doesn't take a list, I don't think that's necessary. Source code -  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context%2Cint%2Cint%29

Comment: @cricket_007 This was a stab in the dark...now I'm really confused. I don't see anything wrong with the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce your results.

[image: emulator]

Here's the code I tried.

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner);

        Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.contacts_spinner);
        Spinner s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.howOften_spinner);

        final int adapterItemLayout = android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item;
        final int dropdownItemLayout = android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> resourceAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.howOften, adapterItemLayout);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dynamicAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, adapterItemLayout);

        resourceAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(dropdownItemLayout);
        dynamicAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(dropdownItemLayout);

        s1.setAdapter(resourceAdapter);
        s2.setAdapter(dynamicAdapter);

        dynamicAdapter.add("bla - 1");
        dynamicAdapter.add("bla - 2");

    }
}
```